# Add .next() every time a function is called

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I basically want to know if its possible to add another `.next()` every time the function is called, this is the function i have at the moment which sort of works but it always brings up the same post which isn't what I am looking for it to do.

```
function nextPost() {
        $('#post_content_container').on('scroll', function() {
            if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
                var post_link = $('.post_link').next().attr("href");
                $("#post_content_container").html("content loading");
                $("#post_content_container").load(post_link);
                return false;
            }
        })
    }
```

If there is a more efficient way of doing this without using `.next()` then it would be great if you could shed a line on how to do it.

here is a gif showing the sort of thing i want it to do
https://i.gyazo.com/62037256b743a9022080a3095131e4e4.gif it gets the links from the posts in the middle column and then when you reach the bottom of the div on the right it would load the next post in the list.

Comment: Tried `.parent().find('.foo')`?

Comment: yeah, didnt work ;(

Comment: Could you add a little more detail to your question. Why do you need an additional `next()` call on successive clicks? I assume you're adding an element to the DOM. Seeing what that content is, along with your HTML, may help.

Comment: I've just added a bit more to my question, I hope that helps :)

Comment: Don’t use .next, but something like .children or .find to get all relevant elements in question - and then select one of those via its index. Use a variable for the index that you increment by one each time (plus reset it, when it reaches the end.)

Comment: thanks CBoe that seems like a much better way of doing this :D